# PHP & KML file: how to decode utf8 encoded name in KML file?

Tags: php, utf-8, kml, decode

I have to parse KML file in PHP. The name of placemarks in the KML file is UTF8 encoded like this:

```
<name>xD0<U+1ED3>ng ThxE1p</name>
```

which should be "Đồng Tháp". How can I correctly parse it in PHP? Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see coding is for utf-16. Not utf8
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1ed3/index.htm

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. Yeah that is UTF-16. I tried mp_convert_encoding($name,'utf-8','auto') but no help. Maybe have to first convert XML encoded string to raw utf-16 string then next... Please help me. THank you!

Comment: function kmlname2html($str){

 $str = preg_replace('/x([0-9A-F]+)/','&#x${1};',$str);

 $str = preg_replace('/<U\+([0-9A-F]+)>/','&#x${1};',$str); 

 return $str; 
}

Comment: I got the string correctly in html entities encoding. How could I get utf8 representation so that I can use it as file name? mb_convert_encoding($str,'utf-8','auto') is no help. Still html entities in file name. Any help pls?